# Get newer version of QGIS

Tags: software-installation, qgis

I installed QGIS like so:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade  
subo apt-get install qgis
```

I now have this version:
2.18 Las Palmas de G.C

It says there is a newer version availble. If I follow that link I end up here:
https://qgis.org/ubuntu/

This is a list of 4 directories.
Now what?

Comment: Thank you. I followed the instructions you link to and now have 3.4 Madiera. I also followed the instructions to add the gpg key and afaict, that worked.

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Comment: Delete question. No, I don't think so. It might be easy to find this for others interested in QGIS-3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://qgis.org/ubuntu/ is a separate repository.

HowTo add qgis-3 to Ubuntu → https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133033/installing-latest-qgis-version-on-ubuntu : QGIS 3.x will run on Ubuntu 18.04 ...

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
```

The gpg.key will have to be added too.