# Install latest QGIS version

Tags: qgis

I have been trying to install the latest version of QGIS but can't get anything other than version 3.22.

Most instructions (including those on the QGIS website) have a step where you need to edit the `qgis.sources` file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. I have some other source files in this location but nothing for qgis.

I also tried to follow the steps given [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207591/get-newer-version-of-qgis) but ended up with the same version.

What am I missing?

Running Ubuntu 22.04.01 Jammy

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133033/installing-latest-qgis-version-on-ubuntu <- follow the most voted answer and it should work. Keep in mind you're supposed to replace "codename" in the first command by your release's codename, "jammy".

Comment: qgis in the Ubuntu repositories is indeed stuck at 3.22. The reasons are detailed at https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/qgis . Volunteers to help solve those problems are welcome.